# How to return Multiple rows of data/objects using a filter in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

Please help me
How can i return/query Multiple rows of Objects using a filter in django
ex.
campus = the_campus
I have a field named campus in my table and i want to query all objects with the value given.....

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

```
'NameOfModel'.objects.filter(campus=the_campus)
```

Comment: hahaha my mistake i was just worried beacause no datas are showing up... turns out i just missed called the {% block (nameoftheblock) %}